# Unable to run KinectAvatarsDemo for Kinect version 2 with KinectWapper

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, kinect

I try to use KinectWrapper from http://rfilkov.com/2013/12/16/kinect-with-ms-sdk/ to integrate Kinect with Unity. Following the instruction given in this package, I am able to import the package to my project and I can see KinectAvatarsDemo.unity under Assert/KinectDemo/AvatarsDemo. After double clicking the  KinectAvatarsDemo.unity file, nothing much happened. Also I could not see any avatar in the scene. When I run it, nothing happened. The Kinect is not turned on. So I have no idea what shall I do to run the demo. I am sure the MS-SDK for Kinect version 2 is correctly install. Can any one show me a more detailed instruction on using the package? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using Kinect for window V2 device. The KinectWrapper provided in http://rfilkov.com/2013/12/16/kinect-with-ms-sdk/ is for kinect for windows v1. It doesn't support kinect for windows v2. To use unity with Kinect for windows V2, you need to use plug in for Kinect V2. You can get the plug in from [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c3b67b6-3fe2-4789-b2df-eb63419e7ab6/kinect-for-windows-v2-sdk-now-available?forum=kinectv2sdk). This is official Kinect for windows V2 plug in for Unity. And it contains two examples inside it and other instructions to use it.

There is also an unofficial paid asset [Kinect V2 MS-SDK](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/18708) in asset store. You can also check free asset [FreeKinectV2 Bone](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19873).

Comment: Yes, I got  Kinect V2 MS-SDK in asset store. Not the one for version 1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, as stated in the asset description "'Kinect with MS-SDK' is a set of Kinect v1 examples..." At the time of the initial K1-asset release there was no Kinect v2. :)